# Windows CE 6.0 time setting in registry

Tags: timezone, registry, windows-ce

So I have a Motorola MC3100 Mobile Barcode scanning device with Windows CE 6.0.

Now I want to get the device to sync its date/time on boot up with our domain controller using some registry files that I have created.

I have used these 2 registry files below to get close to what I require.

---

REG 1

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\TIMESVC]
"UserProcGroup"=dword:00000002
"Flags"=dword:00000010
"multicastperiod"=dword:36EE80
"threshold"=dword:5265C00
"recoveryrefresh"=dword:36EE80
"refresh"=dword:5265C00
"Context"=dword:0
"Autoupdate" = dword:1 
"server" = "NAMEOFMYSERVER" (obviously I have the real name in the actual reg file)
"ServerRole" = dword:0
"Trustlocalclock" = dword:0 
"Dll"="timesvc.dll"
"Order"=dword:0000000b
"Keep"=dword:1
"Prefix"="NTP"
"Index"=dword:0
```

Reg 2

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time]
@ = "UTC"
"TZI"=hex:\
      00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
      00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time Zones]
@ = "UTC"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Microsoft\Clock]
"AutoDST" =dword:0
```

---

Now it gets the correct date and shows the time zone correctly however the time is always 5 hours behind on Pacific Standard Time, which is really annoying.

I cannot find any other setting to get it to set the time correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  This question is better asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), and appears to have [already been asked before](http://superuser.com/questions/373187/timezone-issues-on-windows-ce-6-0).

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at that article and I have set the reg key to match what it suggests, but it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to have a stab....

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time Zones]
@ = "UTC" <---- this value will need to be changed to what ever word it requires UTC would be GMT: Greenwich Mean Time 
possibly set the time manually to what ever and check what word gets filled in then copy it to your reg file?

Comment: That's what all the Zeros in the hex represent, it's been a while so im not 100%.