# Programatically configure Windows Mobile to use an NTP server

Tags: timezone, windows-mobile, ntp

On Windows CE, the NTP settings are [stored under `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\TIMESVC]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15243805/11683) and can be programmatically changed if needed.

That key does not seem to exist on Windows Mobile, and I could not find any information on how to make the exact same thing on this platform. All resources seem to be discussing Windows CE.

How do I programmatically tell Windows Mobile to use a certain NTP server?

Comment: Could you please clarify *specifically* which version of Windows you are asking about?  Do you mean something like the ancient [Windows Mobile 6.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile), or do you mean like current [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) platform?

Comment: @MattJohnson I mean something like [Windows Mobile 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile#Windows_Mobile_5).

Comment: Good luck with that. (sincerely - I'd help if I could, but it's an ancient platform)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but on Windows desktop / server, this is at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters\NtpServer
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no NTP service running on Windows Mobile. The OEM may have included one or not, that is an option for a certified Windows Mobile device.

There are several free and commercial NTP clients out there for Windows Mobile 6.x.

Normally Windows Mobile 6.5x supports NITZ and that is NTP via WWAN connection. See the Settings on your device.